# Simple Admin User with Laravel 5.2 Authentication

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, admin

I've setup Laravel's built in authentication feature, but it doesn't have an admin. I've been looking up ways to do this, but many tutorials seem a bit weighty. I wanted as simple, safe solution that takes advantage of the users table I already have.

I've looked at this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/user-admin-authentication

The instructions come from several users, and it's a bit hard to follow. I've set up a "isAdmin" column to my users database. I have a middleware for the admin, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I don't forget anything, this should be enough.

Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //...
    'isAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdminMiddleware::class,
];
```

IsAdminMiddleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!\Auth::user()->isAdmin){
        return Redirect::route('index');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

routes.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isAdmin']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.index');
    Route::get('/add-user', 'AdminController@addUser')->name('admin.addUser');
});
```

**The lazy solution, not recommended:**

In you `AdminController`, add the following:

```
public function __construct(){
    if(!\Auth::user()->isAdmin){
        dd('Redirect user or whatever, this is where all but admin gets stucked');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I get:

FatalThrowableError in IsAdmin.php line 17:
Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Auth' not found

Comment: Use backslash before Auth::user()->isAdmin. I have updated the example.

Comment: It worked well, but now I can't access the page that I made for admins. I'm not sure it's recognizing that I'm an admin? my database table as a boolean column for isAdmin. 1 for true and 0 for false, right? Why isn't it recognizing me as an admin?

Comment: I found a bug.. I added a `!` in `if(!\Auth::user()->isAdmin){`. You want it to send the user to a different route if the user isn't admin.. Please add the ! and try again :)